# ¿Cómo se llama una cría de iguana?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, nombres-propios, animales

Mi pregunta es si las crías de iguana tienen otro nombre aparte. Encontré una lista de crías en [wikilingua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lista_de_cr%C3%ADas_de_animales), pero no encontré este animal.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Si no existe una palabra específica, la RAE recoge el sufijo [-ato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4GZKKGk) que, aplicado a animales, especifica la cría de estos. Pone como ejemplos el cervato y el ballenato. Del mismo modo supongo que podría decirse, por qué no, **iguanato**.</strike>

Que no, que me dice la RAE en [un tuit](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/818790433350385664) que naranjas de la China, que "iguanato" no está en el diccionario y su uso no está documentado. Además, y aunque dice que *iguanato* [no sería una incorrección](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/819189018181140480), confirma que el sufijo «-ato» no se puede aplicar a cualquier base. Me temo que de momento habrá que llamarla "cría de iguana".

Comment: Iguanato? Será iguanito?  :-)

Comment: @DGaleano pues va a ser que sí :D

Comment: Además es "iguanito" a la mamá pero pequeñito. :-)

Comment: @DGaleano madre del amor hermoso, qué malo... :D

Comment: No recordaba la expresión [_naranjas de la China_](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-expresiones-como-naranjas-de-la-china-o-nanay-de-la-china/), ¡qué buena!

Comment: @fedorqui En Colombia solo decimos "naranjas chinas" o "nanay"

Comment: @fedorqui viene hasta [recogido en la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QEs8tdX#BQfFoTY): "para negar o rechazar algo con rotundidad".